# How to increase POST data size

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a form:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="frm" name="frm">
```

I have 2 inputs inside this form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="obj1" id="obj1">
<input type="text" name="obj2" id="obj2">
```

User fills the text input, and hidden input is filled by jquery script:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $("#obj1").val('very big json string about 4mb');
    $("#frm").submit();
});
```

`nodejs` server is used as backend.

```
function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body.obj1.length);
}
```

This returns 1048576. It equals to 1mb. Something slices the data. How can I send and receive more than 1mb data? Where is the problem ?

Comment: Would help if you provided more detail...  Are you using express as well?

Comment: Usually it is configured on server

Comment: yes, i use express

Comment: Also do you use `body-parser` middleware ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is:

html:

```
<input type="hidden" maxlength="52428800">
```

nodejs:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '50mb' }));
```